# Integrating OverlappingMarkerSpidifier with our code

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My team and I are working on a group project that plots incidents around College Station, TX. Most of the markers are located at one coordinate, so we're trying to integrate the [`OverlappingMarkerSpidifier`](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) code with ours, but I'm not quite sure how to do it. Could anyone help with this?

The code works for the most part, or at least the markers populate where they need to and I can get an infowindow to pop up for the topmost marker. The main issue is figuring out to transform this (from the above website):

```
for (var i = 0; i < window.mapData.length; i ++) {
  var datum = window.mapData[i];
  var loc = new L.LatLng(datum.lat, datum.lon);
  var marker = new L.Marker(loc);
  marker.desc = datum.d;
  map.addLayer(marker);
  oms.addMarker(marker);  // <-- here
}
```

into something that will loop through our data instead.

**Note**: The original code had JSON values within it, but those have been removed for this post. Additionally, since this will probably make a difference, we hard coded our JSON data (I know, it's terrible practice, but we needed to do it at the time to start working with the map code itself)

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #mapcanvas {
                height: 300px;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 300px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/bin/oms.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            //Load and center map on college station
            var map;
             
            function initialize() {

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 12,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.628769, -96.334816)
                };
             
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcanvas'), mapOptions);
                
                //Create info window     
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: ''
                });    
             
                //Get and parse JSON data    
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("button").click(function(){
                        $.each(data.items, handleItem);
                    });
                });
             
                function handleItem(i, items) {
                    $('#placeholder').append("<li>Coord: " + items.lat + items.long + "Category:" + items.category + "</li>");
         
                    //Info window content 
                    var contentString = '<div id=content">'+
                    'Incident Notice'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<p id = "firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + items.category + '<br></br>' + items.lat + ", " + items.long + '</p>' +
                    '</div>'
                    'Location: Texas A&M'

                    var img = 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png';
                    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(items.lat, items.long);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatLng,
                        map: map,
                        icon: img
                    });

                    //Create info window on click and close when clicking a new marker
                    var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);
                    
                    oms.addListener('click', function(marker, event) {
                        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                    
                    oms.addListener('spiderfy', function(markers) {
                        for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i ++) {
                            markers[i].setIcon(iconWithColor(spiderfiedColor));
                            markers[i].setShadow(null);
                        } 
                        iw.close();
                    });

                    oms.addListener('unspiderfy', function(markers) {
                        for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i ++) {
                            markers[i].setIcon(iconWithColor(usualColor));
                            markers[i].setShadow(shadow);
                        }
                    });

                    oms.addMarker(marker);
                }
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mapcanvas"></div>
        <button>Get and Parse</button>
        <p>
         
        </p>
        <ul id="placeholder">
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: Yeah, I played around with adding in what he said in the basic code at the bottom of the page. But since he uses variables like 'gm' in his code and a somewhat different base map construction, I'm not entirely sure how to incorporate his code without completely changing what we already have. We're in a beginning WebGIS course so we're all a little new to doing this and coding in general.

Comment: The `handleItem` function is inside `initialize` function. That's right?

Comment: According to one of the labs we did earlier in the semester, this works. And we haven't had a problem with it so far.

Comment: See my answer, may can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many problems with your code:

- declare `oms` as global variable, only one instance, this will facilitate the use;
- `iconWithColor` is not defined;
- `shadow` is not defined;
- on **spiderfy** listener, you are calling `iw.close();`. `iw` is not defined and is not the added in `click` listener. Change body of function to `infoWindow.close();`;

Se an example, may can help you:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #mapcanvas {
                height: 300px;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 300px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/bin/oms.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var map;
            var oms;
            
            //Create info window (need only one)  
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
             
            function initialize() {

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 12,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.628769, -96.334816)
                };

                //Load and center map on college station
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcanvas'), mapOptions);
                
                oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);

                // listeners need to be registered only once
                oms.addListener('click', function(marker, event) {
                    infowindow.setContent(marker.description);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });

                oms.addListener('spiderfy', function(markers) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                        // markers[i].setIcon(iconWithColor(spiderfiedColor));
                        markers[i].setShadow(null);
                    } 
                    infowindow.close();
                });

                oms.addListener('unspiderfy', function(markers) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                        // markers[i].setIcon(iconWithColor(usualColor));
                        // markers[i].setShadow(shadow);
                    }
                });
                
                function handleItem(items) {
                    $('#placeholder').append("<li>Coord: " + items.lat + items.long + " Category: " + items.category + "</li>");

                    //Info window content 
                    var contentString = '<div id=content">'+
                    'Incident Notice'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<p id = "firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + items.category + '<br></br>' + items.lat + ", " + items.long + '</p>' +
                    '</div>'
                    'Location: Texas A&M'

                    var img = 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png';
                    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(items.lat, items.long);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatLng,
                        map: map,
                        icon: img
                    });
                    
                    // to be possible in "click" show specific content
                    marker.description = contentString;

                    oms.addMarker(marker);
                }

                //Get and parse JSON data    
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("button").click(function(){
                        $.each(data.items, handleItem);
                    });
                });
                
                var item = {
                    lat: 30.628769,
                    long: -96.334816,
                    category: "Category - "
                };

                // for test only
                for(var i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
                    item.category += i;
                    handleItem(item);
                }
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mapcanvas"></div>
        <button>Get and Parse</button>
        <p></p>
        <ul id="placeholder">
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```